# How long-lived is a sharedData AsyncMap in Vert.x?

Tags: java, vert.x

If I fetch an `AsyncMap` like so:

```
if (vertx.isClustered()) {
    vertx.sharedData().<String, MyEntity>getClusterWideMap("entities", 
            res -> {
                AsyncMap<String, MyEntity> myMap = res.result();
                // Do something with the myMap
            });
}
```

How "long-lived" is the map?  Does it keep itself in sync?

Can I fetch it in a constructor, stash in a field, and use it over and over?

Or do I need to call getClusterWideMap each time I need it and only use it within the lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a reference to the `AsyncMap`. Calling `getClusterWideMap` again will give you another reference to the same underlying data structure, provided by the cluster manager.

Comment: the old reference should still work just fine, shouldn't it?